# Why must callers use a constructor instead of creating a struct directly?

Tags: rust

Consider the following Rust snippet [from *The Rust Programming Language*, second edition](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/book/second-edition/ch09-03-to-panic-or-not-to-panic.html):

```
pub struct Guess {
    value: u32,
}

impl Guess {
    pub fn new(value: u32) -> Guess {
        if value < 1 || value > 100 {
            panic!("Guess value must be between 1 and 100, got {}.", value);
        }

        Guess {
            value
        }
    }

    pub fn value(&self) -> u32 {
        self.value
    }
}
```

and commentary from the corresponding tutorial, emphasis mine:

> Next, we implement a method named `value` that borrows `self`, doesn’t have any
>   other parameters, and returns a `u32`. This is a kind of method sometimes
>   called a *getter*, since its purpose is to get some data from its fields and
>   return it. This public method is necessary because the `value` field of the
>   `Guess` struct is private. It’s important that the `value` field is private so
>   that code using the `Guess` struct is not allowed to set `value` directly:
>   **callers outside the module *must* use the `Guess::new` function to create an
>   instance of `Guess`,  which ensures there’s no way for a `Guess` to have a
>   `value` that hasn’t been checked by the conditions in the `Guess::new` function**.

Why must callers use the `new` function? Couldn't they get around the requirement that `Guess.value` be between 1 and 100 by doing something like:

```
let g = Guess { value: 200 };
```

Comment: Look at the sentence before the highlighted one: "It’s important that the value field is private so that code using the Guess struct is not allowed to set value directly".

Comment: *Couldn't they get around the requirement* — did you **try** to write some code outside the module that "gets around the requirement"? If you had, you'd quickly see the compiler error that prevents you.

Answer (score 11):

This applies only when the `Guess` struct is defined in a different module than the code using it; the struct itself is public but its `value` field is not, so you can't access it directly.

You can verify it with the following example ([playground link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=565509e40aaa28986b88413f459a75b2&version=stable)):

```
use self::guess::Guess;

fn main() {
    let guess1 = Guess::new(20); // works
    let guess2 = Guess::new(200); // panic: 'Guess value must be between 1 and 100, got 200.'
    let guess3 = Guess { value: 20 }; // error: field `value` of struct `guess::Guess` is private
    let guess4 = Guess { value: 200 }; // error: field `value` of struct `guess::Guess` is private
}

mod guess {
    pub struct Guess {
        value: u32,
    }

    impl Guess {
        pub fn new(value: u32) -> Guess {
            if value < 1 || value > 100 {
                panic!("Guess value must be between 1 and 100, got {}.", value);
            }

            Guess {
                value
            }
        }

        pub fn value(&self) -> u32 {
            self.value
        }
    }
}
```

The Book explains the rationale behind keeping a struct's contents private pretty well.

Comment: Conversely, if you *want* the `Guess` value constructor to be public, all you have to do is mark all its members `pub`.